# Output of Faster RCNN

Tags: object-detection, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn

is it possible to get 3 bounding box of a single class in Faster RCNN?
In my work, I want to get 3 top suggestion from Faster RCNN.
e.g. Suppose my model is looking for apples in a tree. So there could be so many apples in a tree but I want to get the top 3 as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Faster RCNN classifies each detection individually so there can be any number of detections for a given class. You can filter out any detections except the class you are interested in and then look for the 3 detections with the highest confidence.

You can do this really easily in the visualization tool [FiftyOne](https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone):

[R-CNN model predictions in FiftyOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4znWi.gif)